# Why doesn't java compiler tell 'cannot cast error' for this casting?

Tags: java

I just got confused with one java compilation scenario  which behaves odd with the given problem.

The below code will give compilation error (cannot cast types),because A and B are distinct classes and they have no relation between them.

```
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        B b1 = (B)a;
        A a1 = (A)b;
```

In the same way, If I cast the List and Map to each other ,it should give me compilation error.But its not giving any such error,ofcourse i am getting ClassCastException at runtime.

```
        List<String> listObj = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<Integer,Float> mapObj = new HashMap<Integer,Float>();

        Map newMapObj = (Map) listObj;
        List newListObj = (List) mapObj;
```

What could be the reason for this adjustment...

Answer (score 7):

That's because `Map` and `List` are interfaces, and you can have a class that implements both. This is not valid for classes, as multiple inheritance is not possible in Java.

---

Even if such use cases make the compiler look quite dumb (as it's obvious that in this context the cast will never succeed), it wouldn't make much sense to deep dive into the initialization code, as this would require tracking all the possible assignments to that reference:

```
List<String> someOtherList = getSomeOtherList();
List<String> listObj = someOtherList != null ? someOtherList : new ArrayList<String>();
```

This would make it unfeasible for the compiler to be able to say what kind of `List` the `listObj` will be after this line.

Even with your simple example, the compiler needs to track that between your initial declaration of the `listObj` and the cast attempt there is no other assignment to that variable (so that it can infer for sure that `listObj` is definitely an `ArrayList`). Such tracking can become painful to impossible once other lines of code are placed between the assignment and the cast.

---

But I do agree that such compiler limitations can be frustrating; I sometimes find annoying the fact that the following does not compile:

```
final int i;
try {
    i = Integer.parseInt("someString");
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    i = -1;
}
```

... because "variable 'i' might already have been assigned to", which is obviously not possible. But the compiler doesn't actually care what's in my `try` block, it *assumes* that a `NumberFormatException` can be thrown by some line of code after that assignment; so `i` cannot be declared `final`.

Comment: +1, makes me wonder why the compiler does not realize that by static analysis of the method though, there is no way for the code to actually succeed in this simple case since the values are assigned only once to a static type.

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu... in my problem, The ArrayList class doesn't implemet Map interface and HashMap doesn't implement List...So how come the complier lets this snippet to pass?...

Comment: Indeed, but the compiler doesn't check that. It only checks the *declared* types of your references (which are Map and List).